# "who" shows wrong users list, although they are logged out

Tags: linux

Using the 'who' command I get a wrong list of users.

The symptoms are that I keep getting users that exited (logged out) the machine.

I'm sure the users are logged out as this is an embedded system under development that the only access to it is from my own computer. The 'users' are users that I create and manage.
The linux running on this device was taken from scratch and is built with the relevant packages as needed.

Linux kernel is 3.4.52 and 'who' is busybox.

I changed nsswitch.conf including writing my own nss-module. However, I can't see any reason that my activity should change the utmp file.

I would like to get help, or at least a starting point to look at.

Comment: Define "wrong". Are you sure the users have logged out of *all things* that would create a session in the `utmp` file? Have you verified that the data presented is actually incorrect? If so you may have found an actual bug in your operating system, and should report it to your OS vendor (or you could ask us about the specific edge case you've encountered that's causing login sessions to linger). As it stands right now you're making an assertion - you're not asking an *answerable* question...

Comment: Revised my question, added details, please reopen it.

Comment: Is the session still active on a process listing? Sounds like they haven't actually logged out.

Comment: no active session.